# How to populate message box from a text box when user enters a value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using 3 text boxes for range selections. I want to show range value in a message box when user enters range in text box.

Suppose user enters

1. 100 in 1st text box , I want to show "you are selected <100".
2. 100  in 1st text box and 500 in 2nd text box I want to show "you are selected 101 - 500"
3. 500 in 2nd text box and 1000 in 3rd text box I want to show "you are selected  501 - 1000"

After entering a value in 3rd text box ,I want to show all ranges in message box.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example I've coded

http://jsbin.com/ovepo4

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use some javascript to get the values from each text box, and display those values in a messagebox via the `alert` function.

Assuming your textboxes are called 'first', 'second' and 'third' it would look something like this:

```
var firstValue = document.getElementByName('first').value;
var firstValue = document.getElementByName('second').value
var firstValue = document.getElementByName('third').value
```

If you're using jQuery you can do it like so:

```
var firstValue = $('#first').val();
var secondValue = $('#second').val();
var thirdValue = $('#third').val();
```

With these values you can do some logic, and display your message, ie:

```
if(firstValue < 100) {
    alert('You entered < 100');
}
```

And so on.